# Select statment from multiple tables, with variable input

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have two tables: `AreaCode` and `EquipmentNumber`.

```
+------------------------------------+
| AreaCd                             |
|------------------------------------|
| AreaID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT |
| Code INT                           |
| Name CHAR(30)                      |
| Comments TEXT                      |
| PKEY (AreaID)                      |
+------------------------------------+
+------------------------------------+
| EqNum                              |
|------------------------------------|
| EqID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT   |
| AreaID INT                         |
| Number CHAR(5)                     | 
| Type CHAR(10)                      |
| PKEY (EqID)                        |
| FKEY (AreaID) REF AreaCode(AreaID) |
+------------------------------------+
```

I want to extract `EqNum.Number`, `Eq.Type` and `AreaCd.Code`. The trouble is, that the query is populated by input from a form, so the search restrictions are variable. I have created 3 seperate queries similar to these:

```
"SELECT Number, Type, Code FROM EqNum, AreaCd " +
"WHERE EqNum.AreaId = AreaCd.AreaId AND Code = " + int nCode + ";";

"SELECT Number, Type, Code FROM EqNum, AreaCd " +
"WHERE EqNum.AreaId = AreaCd.AreaId AND Number = '" + string sNumber + "';";

"SELECT Number, Type, Code FROM EqNum, AreaCd " +
"WHERE EqNum.AreaId = AreaCd.AreaId AND Type = '" + string sType + "';";
```

Which all work fine on their own, provided the user is only searching for one column (`Code`, `Number`, *or* `Type`) at a time, but I need the capability to search for one, two, *or* all three columns at once.

I have tried using `OR`, `LIKE`, multiple selection, I've even tried casting `int nCode` as a char to use the `%` wildcard, but I just can't find something that works.

**QUESTION: Can someone help me join these three queries to search the tables for any combination of all three felds: `EqNum.Number`, `EqNum.Type` and `AreaCd.Code` that will refine the search result when more fields are added?** (i.e. a search for `EqNum.Type` will yield more results than a search for `EqNum.Number`, `EqNum.Type` and `AreaCd.Code`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT e.Number, e.Type, a.Code
FROM EqNum e INNER JOIN AreaCd a
ON e.AreaId = a.AreaId
WHERE (@Number IS NULL OR e.Number = @Number)
AND (@Type IS NULL OR e.Type = @Type)
AND (@Code IS NULL OR a.Code = @Code)
```

To learn how to use parameters with ADO.NET, [click here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html).

Setting parameters would look something like this:

```
command.Parameters["@Number"].Value = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(number) ? (object) DBNull.Value : number);
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that you then set the Value of any parameters that you don't want to use to NULL (DBNull.Value in ADO.NET) and they are effectively ignored.

Comment: None of the fields in the table will be NULL though? Only the input for the query could be empty?

Comment: Read the code!  It compares the parameters to NULL, not the columns.  As such, that means that if a parameter is NULL then all columns match, which is functionally equivalent to ignoring that parameter altogether, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: woops! sorry I missed that haha

Comment: I've added a C# code snippet for setting a parameter value in code.

Comment: ADO.NET I meant to say haha.

Comment: Thanks this is working great! I also added in `e.Number LIKE @Number` to allow wildcard `%`. You're a lifesaver!

Comment: Hi, I recently lost some of my project and I am trying to recreate this portion of it but there is something I'm missing because I can't get this code working again. I have asked the related question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669569/parameter-name-not-found-in-the-collection/23669732?noredirect=1#23669732

Comment: can I use this with an `int` or `double` input? so far as I know, this just uses `string` input so it compares with NULL (i.e. `NULL IS NULL OR AreaCode LIKE NULL`) but can it work with `0 IS NULL OR AreaCode LKE 0`?

Comment: What I have shown works with absolutely any data type.  Just do what I have said and stop trying to complicate things.  Use a parameter and pass `NULL` if you want it ignored.  It's that simple.  It doesn't matter what the data type is because `NULL` is valid for any data type.  You obviously wouldn't use `LIKE` with numbers though, because it is only valid for comparing strings.  The operator is irrelevant though, e.g. this is valid for a numeric column: `@Amount IS NULL OR Amount > @Amount`.

Comment: Honestly not trying to complicate things. My ignorance is getting the better of me. I can't get this to work because I need the `@Amount` to be an `int`, and `Amount > @Amount` won't work for me either because I need `Amount = @Amount`

Comment: Where did I say that you have to use `Amount > @Amount`?  Do you not know the meaning of the word "example"?  In my original answer I used `=` so obviously it works with `=`.  If it's not working for you then it's because you're doing it wrong.  If you just do what I said to do then it will work.  It doesn't matter what comparison operator you use and it doesn't matter what data type the columns/parameters are.  It will work regardless.  I've already told you what to do so do it.  If it's not working then we're not going to guess what you've done wrong so give us some useful information.

Comment: Your answer is incomplete because you have not provided enough information on other data types. I have attempted to use variations of `int?` with `Code.HasValue`, and `Code.GetValueOrDefault(0) == 0` however this does not return the desired results. I can only get this to work with `string` type parameters. Do you know how to define this query with `int` type parameters?

Comment: I have answered the question as asked completely. You are apparently unable to put 2 and 2 together. The SQL code I have provided is completely independent of data type. If what you're saying, without actually saying, is that you don't know how to test a `int?` to determine whether to set the parameter to `NULL` or not then that's another topic. It's something that you could have asked another question for but it probably would have been voted down because it's something that a couple of minutes with the documentation could tell you: `var.HasValue ? var.Value : (obj) DBNull.Value`.

Comment: My apologies for the lack of clarity. As I have stated before I am a beginner at this and so my knowledge in this area is really quite minimal. Thankyou for your patience and assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after :

Just added a simple trick;

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sNumber))
    sNumber="$$$";               //If sNumber is empty, then selection using sNumber= '$$$' will return nothing.
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sType))
    sType="$$$"                 //If sType is empty, then selection using sType = '$$$' will return nothing.
"SELECT Number, Type, Code FROM EqNum, AreaCd " +
"WHERE EqNum.AreaId = AreaCd.AreaId 
AND 
  (Code = " + int nCode + " 
   OR Number = '" + string sNumber + "' 
   OR Type = '" + string sType + "')"
```

**OR** using `LIKE`:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sNumber))
    sNumber="$$$";             //If sNumber is empty, then selection using sNumber LIKE '%$$$%' will return nothing.
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sType))
    sType="$$$"                //If sType is empty, then selection using sType LIKE '%$$$%' will return nothing.
"SELECT Number, Type, Code FROM EqNum, AreaCd " +
"WHERE EqNum.AreaId = AreaCd.AreaId 
AND 
  (Code = " + int nCode + "
   OR Number LIKE '%" + string sNumber + "%' 
   OR Type LIKE '%" + string sType + "%')"
```

See an example at [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c65c5/10)

Comment: The trouble is that some of the search fields could be empty. So for example it could be `Code = 110`, 'Number = '(empty)'`, `Type = (empty`. OR None of the fields could be empty. I don't think this covers that.

Comment: there's a possibility that `Code` could be 0, (empty). Sorry if I was unclear, it is a really complex question haha

Comment: Doesn't matter, it will do the trick. See the example in Fiddle. provide different parameters. To ignore a condition assign 0 to `Code` and `$$$` to other parameters.

Comment: ahhh! so close! I did the query and it all worked well, but when I tried searching for all 3 fields at once, it didn't refine the search :(

Comment: What parameters have you tried? See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c65c5/11).

Comment: that's not what I'm looking for. For example if I'm looking for 'secName A' in 'ID 2', I want that query to not find results, because those parameters don't coincide. I want to be able to refine my search by adding more parameters. The more I look at it, the harder it seems to become :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  SELECT Number, Type, Code FROM EqNum, AreaCd " +
   "WHERE EqNum.AreaId = AreaCd.AreaId AND 
   isnull(Code,0) = " + int nCode + " or
    isnull(Number,0) = '" + string sNumber + "' or isnull(Type,0) = '" + string sType + "'
```