# Parameter "@Name" not found in the collection

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, parameters

I have come across this solution recently as part of another problem I was having when trying to select from multiple tables which variable or null input on three fields. [Here is the original post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316374/select-statment-from-multiple-tables-with-variable-input)

Unfortunately I am still a little unfamiliar with ADO.NET and I am getting this error when I run my code:

`Parameter "@AreaName" not found in the collection`

Here is the code for the query:

```
mySqlConnect.Open();

mySqlCommand = mySqlConnect.CreateCommand();
mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM PlantAreaCodes WHERE (@AreaCode IS NULL OR AreaCode LIKE " + PModel.AreaCode + " OR @AreaName IS NULL OR LIKE " + PModel.AreaName + " OR @Comments IS NULL OR Comments LIKE " + PModel.Comments + ";";
mySqlCommand.Parameters["@AreaCode"].Value = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(PModel.AreaCode)) ? (object)DBNull.Value : PModel.AreaCode);
mySqlCommand.Parameters["@AreaName"].Value = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PModel.AreaName) ? (object)DBNull.Value : PModel.AreaName);
mySqlCommand.Parameters["@Comments"].Value = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PModel.Comments) ? (object)DBNull.Value : PModel.Comments);
mySqlReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

The values passed in are:

```
PModel.AreaCode = 110;
AreaName = null;
Comments = null;
```

I have completed this once before, however I unfortunately lost a segment of my code recently and have had to rebuild.

Comment: You are adding two @AreaCode parameters. Should the second be @Comments?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Doesn't make much difference anyway really...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the parameters before specifying a value:

```
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@AreaName", SqlDbType.VarChar);

mySqlCommand.Parameters["@AreaName"].Value =
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(PModel.AreaName))
        ? (object)DBNull.Value : PModel.AreaName));
```

Consider using this alternate syntax:

```
mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AreaName",
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(PModel.AreaName))
        ? (object)DBNull.Value : PModel.AreaName));
```

You can find a brief example of each on the [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page at MSDN.

---

Also, you've done something funky with the query string. This should fix it:

```
mySqlCommand.CommandText =
    "SELECT * FROM PlantAreaCodes WHERE (AreaCode IS NULL OR AreaCode LIKE @AreaCode OR AreaName IS NULL OR AreaName LIKE @AreaName OR Comments IS NULL OR Comments LIKE @Comment;";
```

To get the `LIKE`s to work correctly, you'll probably have to add `%` symbols around your parameter values when you're adding them:

```
var areaName = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(PModel.AreaName))
                   ? (object)DBNull.Value : PModel.AreaName)

mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AreaName", "%" + areaName + "%");
```

Comment: I have code to format the input data so that if there is data, it is formatted to be like '%data%'

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me a rather strange error saying I have a syntax error near 'LIKE NULL) OR (NULL IS NULL OR Comments LIKE NULL'

Comment: Maybe add some single quotes in the LIKE SQL e.g. LIKE '@AreaName'

Comment: actually should have quoted that correctly: all input string are formatted to `'%data%'`.

Comment: Also this has eliminated any errors I was getting, but now it's not returning anything for `@AreaName` or `@Comments`?

Comment: no I mean if I query the `AreaName` or `Comments` nothing is being returned. But if I query `AreaCode`, it returns data

Comment: Try some brackets like my query below.

Comment: Actually I think it's because instead or `AreaCode LIKE null` it is queried as `AreaCode LIKE 0` because `PModel.AreaCode` is an `int`

Comment: @JamesHull I did try that but it didn't make a difference. As I said before I have coded my data to appear as such : `%data%'`

Comment: @GrantWinney, you're right about the parameters but not about the SQL.  The point is to be able to include or exclude parameters from the filter so the SQL should look like this: `SELECT * FROM PlantAreaCodes WHERE (@AreaCode IS NULL OR AreaCode LIKE @AreaCode) AND (@AreaName IS NULL OR AreaName LIKE @AreaName) AND (@Comments IS NULL OR Comments LIKE @Comments)`.  That way, you can pass `NULL` for a parameter and every record matches, effectively ignoring that filter.

Comment: It does look different from your original proposition, and I'm having issues using `int` as a parameter, because instead of `NULL` it passes `0`

Comment: Yes the query that jmcilhinney suggested has worked for me the first time I tried it, however there is some tweaking that needs to be done to it to get it to work correctly IIRC.

Comment: I have figured out the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729067/command-parametersname-value-correct-syntax

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the parameters? Looks like you are just trying to set the value?

Try this.

```
mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AreaCode", PModel.AreaCode == 0 ? (object)DBNull.Value : PModel.AreaCode.ToString());
```

You need to adjust your SQL text also.

```
mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM PlantAreaCodes WHERE (@AreaCode IS NULL OR AreaCode LIKE AreaCode) AND (@AreaName IS NULL OR LIKE @AreaName) AND (@Comments IS NULL OR Comments LIKE @Comments);";
```