# Command.Parameters["@name"].Value Correct syntax

Tags: c#, mysql, parameters

I am attempting to use a query to select everything from a table using one - three parameters;

```
SELECT * FROM PlantAreaCodes 
WHERE (@AreaCode IS NULL OR AreaCode = @AreaCode) 
AND (@AreaName IS NULL OR AreaName LIKE @AreaName) 
AND (@Comments IS NULL OR Comments LIKE @Comments);
```

Here is the c# code for my query:

```
mySqlCommand = mySqlConnect.CreateCommand();

mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM PlantAreaCodes WHERE (@AreaCode IS NULL OR AreaCode = @AreaCode) AND (@AreaName IS NULL OR AreaName LIKE @AreaName) AND (@Comments IS NULL OR Comments LIKE @Comments);";

mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@AreaCode", MySqlDbType.Int32);
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@AreaName", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Comments", MySqlDbType.Text);

mySqlCommand.Parameters["@AreaCode"].Value = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(PModel.AreaCode)) ? (object)DBNull.Value : PModel.AreaCode);
mySqlCommand.Parameters["@AreaName"].Value = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PModel.AreaName) ? (object)DBNull.Value : PModel.AreaName);
mySqlCommand.Parameters["@Comments"].Value = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PModel.Comments) ? (object)DBNull.Value : PModel.Comments);

mySqlReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

This query allows for the user to search for one, two, three or no fields without throwing any errors, however it only works with nullable types. Therefpre since `PModel.AreaCode` is an `int`, the search uses `0` instead of `null`. ie.

```
SELECT * FROM PlantAreaCodes 
WHERE (NULL IS NULL OR AreaCode = NULL) 
AND (NULL IS NULL OR AreaName LIKE NULL) 
AND (NULL IS NULL OR Comments LIKE NULL);
```

Which will return no fields because `AreaCode = 0` is a valid query.

I have tried making `AreaCode` nullable by declaring `int? AreaCode = null`, but this doesn't work. This returns all fields, instead of just one, same as if I used the default `null`:

```
SELECT * FROM PlantAreaCodes 
WHERE (110 IS NULL OR AreaCode = 110) 
AND (NULL IS NULL OR AreaName LIKE NULL) 
AND (NULL IS NULL OR Comments LIKE NULL);
```

However this query returns one field:

```
SELECT * FROM PlantAreaCodes 
WHERE (110 IS NULL OR AreaCode = 110) 
AND ('%General%' IS NULL OR AreaName LIKE '%General%') 
AND (NULL IS NULL OR Comments LIKE NULL);
```

This returns all fields containing the word 'General' in the Name:

```
SELECT * FROM PlantAreaCodes 
WHERE (NULL IS NULL OR AreaCode = NULL) 
AND ('%General%' IS NULL OR AreaName LIKE '%General%') 
AND (NULL IS NULL OR Comments LIKE NULL);
```

How can I use non-nullable types in this query?

Comment: Can you show the C# code you're using to make the database request?

Comment: Have you run the query directly DB to check it works with the input combinations you are going to call it with?

Comment: @PreetSangha Yes the query itself is sound, I believe the issue lies with the `AreaCode` parameter as it is an `int`, so it's default value is `0`, not `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got this working. The main issue was that this needs to compare `null` with `null`, however an `int` can't be `null` as it is a value type.

So I had to do some tweaking with my code and I got this working with the workaround

```
int? AreaCode = null;
```

This allowed me to change up my code:

```
mySqlCommand.Parameters["@AreaCode"].Value = (PModel.AreaCode.HasValue ? PModel.AreaCode.Value : object)DBNull.Value );
```

For all those who aren't aware of what's happening here:

The operator `?` gives a Value Type the ability to *have no value*, so it can = `null`.

ie.

```
int n = 0;
int? n = null;

bool b = false;
bool? b = null;
```