# How can I nest a Select in this query?

Tags: c#, mysql, select

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM CableId WHERE
  (@CblType IS NULL OR CblType LIKE @CblType)
  AND (@CblStatus IS NULL OR CblStatus LIKE @CblStatus)
  AND (@FromLoc IS NULL OR FromLoc LIKE @FromLoc)
  AND (@ToLoc IS NULL OR ToLoc LIKE @ToLoc);
```

The trouble is, that in the database, `FromLoc` and `ToLoc` are stored as foreign keys to another table (MajorEquipment), and there input is selected from a drop down, populated from MajorEquipment.

```
+-----------------------------------------+    +--------------------+
| CableNumber | FromLoc (FK) | ToLoc (FK) |    | MEID (PK) | Equip# |
|-----------------------------------------|    |--------------------|
| 101         | 1            | 2          |    | 1         | CP1    |
+-----------------------------------------+    | 2         | CP2    |
                                               +--------------------+
```

What I want to show is this:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| CableNumber | FromLoc (FK) | ToLoc (FK) |
|-----------------------------------------|
| 101         | CP1          | CP2        |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I need the structure of the original query to stay the same, with possible select queries embedded in it, but I can't get anything to sit right. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316374/select-statment-from-multiple-tables-with-variable-input) is the original demonstration of the query used, for anyone who needs to try and figure out what the query is doing.

Comment: do you want to show the equip place of fromloc and toloc right?

Comment: @SATSON Yes, the 1 and 2 are foreign keys, and I want to show the `Equip#` instead of the `FromLoc`/`ToLoc`.

Comment: @Ben: Please define 'CblType' and 'CblStatus'

Comment: @Vincent, I don't have any issue with those, but they are just standard `Char` input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

`area` is second table name

```
SELECT CableNumber,a.Equip,a1.Equip FROM CableId c 
inner join area a on c.FromLoc=a.MEID
inner join area a1 on c.ToLoc=a1.MEID WHERE
(@CblType IS NULL OR CblType LIKE @CblType)
AND (@CblStatus IS NULL OR CblStatus LIKE @CblStatus)
AND (@FromLoc IS NULL OR a.Equip  LIKE @FromLoc)
AND (@ToLoc IS NULL OR a1.Equip LIKE @ToLoc);
```

Comment: I don't think this will work for me, as the parameters are going to be populated like `@FromLoc = CP1`, not with the foreign key.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the query, but like I said, if I pass in `'CP1' IS NULL OR FromLoc LIKE 'CP1'` which is what I want, it returns nothing

Comment: can you produce sql fiddle for this @Ben

Comment: `@FromLoc` may have null value ah? @Ben

Comment: @Ben Now Look the answer

Comment: @Sathish you have a small typo in the select clause: a2.Equip should be a1.Equip. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, missed that solution :)